# Web scraping with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

My question is about web scraping with Python 3. I found a script to import automatically a CSV file from Yahoo Finance, whose address is : http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL

Now, I want to import some changing values (price of a share, volume, bid, ask) but I don't know how to do that, because when I use my previous script, it imports all the code of the html page into a csv file, whereas I just want to import some values and not the code. The address of the page is : http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?ltr=1.

Anyone has seen such a script?

Comment: There is the Beautiful Soup library: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in financial data provided by Yahoo Finance, you can use the [`yahoo finance python library`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance).

It's [`open source`](https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance) and it has modules that can help you evaluate and analyze historical data.

If you have any questions about the usage of the yahoo-finance library, you can open a stackoverflow question using the [`yahoo-finance tag`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-finance)

Here's a list of all available methods:

```
get_price()
get_change()
get_percent_change()
get_volume()
get_prev_close()
get_open()
get_avg_daily_volume()
get_stock_exchange()
get_market_cap()
get_book_value()
get_ebitda()
get_dividend_share()
get_dividend_yield()
get_earnings_share()
get_days_high()
get_days_low()
get_year_high()
get_year_low()
get_50day_moving_avg()
get_200day_moving_avg()
get_price_earnings_ratio()
get_price_earnings_growth_ratio()
get_price_sales()
get_price_book()
get_short_ratio()
get_trade_datetime()
get_historical(start_date, end_date)
get_info()
get_name()
refresh()
get_percent_change_from_year_high()
get_percent_change_from_year_low()
get_change_from_year_low()
get_change_from_year_high()
get_percent_change_from_200_day_moving_average()
get_change_from_200_day_moving_average()
get_percent_change_from_50_day_moving_average()
get_change_from_50_day_moving_average()
get_EPS_estimate_next_quarter()
get_EPS_estimate_next_year()
get_ex_dividend_date()
get_EPS_estimate_current_year()
get_price_EPS_estimate_next_year()
get_price_EPS_estimate_current_year()
get_one_yr_target_price()
get_change_percent_change()
get_dividend_pay_date()
get_currency()
get_last_trade_with_time()
get_days_range()
get_year_range()
```

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted?

Comment: I don't know either... It would make more sense if the downvoter explained why.

Comment: Thanks dot.Py. I tried to download the yahoo-finance module by running the line : "pip install yahoo-finance" but an error message appears : "invalid syntax". Have you an idea what is not working?

Comment: @AnthonyHauser it works here. Just open a terminal and type: `pip install yahoo-finance`. Note: you **don't** have to run python inside the terminal . Just open it and run `pip install yahoo-finance`.

Comment: Could the python version be a problem here?